# Authenticating multiple non-gallery applications from single Azure Active Directory Enterprise Application

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

I am looking to implement SSO between multiple applications through a single enterprise application I've created on Azure Active Directory.

I've already gotten the first one working through SAML 2 and was wondering whether there was a way each client application would use the Azure Active Directory as the IDP therefore enabling users from the third-party-applications would interact with each other without requiring additional authentication.

I'm not sure the best way to implement such a scenario, majority of the documentation and tutorials I've seen around revolve around a single application using AAD as the IDP

Comment: Do these non-gallery applications run on an Azure tenant? Have you looked at a multi-tenant application approach?

Comment: It's only the application I built that runs on Azure. The rest are independently developed and hosted by third party organisations

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

- Each application integrates with Azure AD in the same way as your application
- Each application has their own IDP that then federates with Azure AD